# Puma in ECS task suddenly takes 10 minutes to boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ecs, puma

I have a docker image of my RoR application running on ECS. All was working fine with the exact same image until about a week ago. Since then my application became unreachable. Upon checking the Logs on ECS, I noticed that somehow my Puma web server is taking almost 10 minutes to boot. This is really strange, as in the same image locally, it takes only a few seconds.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using EC2 or Fargate? If you're on EC2 I'd suggest try downloading the image on the EC2 machine and run docker manually.

Comment: It's Fargate. But after debugging the issue even further, I found that it's no problem that has to do with Puma. I wote a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665237/fargate-taks-can-curl-succesfully-but-the-browser-times-out